# Separating delimited input into variables using >> operator

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++ and I'm trying to experiment with delimited input. I use the following code to get some delimited data and then to separate it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int n1,n2,n3; char data,c; 
    while (std::cin >> data >> c >> n1 >> c >> n2 >> c >> n3 && c == ','){
        std::cout << "Entered loop" << "\n";
        std::cout << "Value:" << data << "\n";
        std::cout << "Value:" << n1 << "\n";
        std::cout << "Value:" << n2 << "\n";
        std::cout << "Value:" << n3 << "\n";
        std::cout << std::endl;
        }
}
```

Input here is something like: A,1,2,3
But if I replace the char data with std::string data like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int n1,n2,n3; std::string data; char c;
    while (std::cin >> data >> c >> n1 >> c >> n2 >> c >> n3 && c == ','){
        std::cout << "Entered loop" << "\n";
        std::cout << "Value:" << data << "\n";
        std::cout << "Value:" << n1 << "\n";
        std::cout << "Value:" << n2 << "\n";
        std::cout << "Value:" << n3 << "\n";
        std::cout << std::endl;
        }
}
```

With input like : ABCD,1,2,3
There is no output which coupled with the debugging "Entered loop" output means that the while loop condition is never fulfilled.

What's going wrong here when I replace char with a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `char` is a single character, one symbol; no less, no more.

A `std::string` may hold *zero or more* characters.

When `operator>>` uses a `char` variable, it reads only one single character.

When `operator>>` uses a `std::string` variable, it first ignores white space characters, then reads characters until a white space character is read.

**Edit 1: `std::getline` and `std::string`**
When reading in text data, prefer to use `std::getline` with `std::string` and specify a terminating character.

For example:

```
std::getline(cin, data, ',');
```

The above will read from `std::cin` until a ',' is read, placing everything except the ',' into the `data` variable.

Comment: So shouldn't replacing string data with char data[4] solve the problem of it reading through to the next white space? Replacing in char data[4] still doesnt do the trick. I know about the getline method to read till the delimiter I was just musing.

Comment: How does the `operator>>` know that the array is 4 characters?  My understanding is that arrays decay to a pointer to the first slot, when passed to a function. What about the terminating nul character?  To avoid defects, you may want to use the `istream::read` function to limit the number of characters read.  Another idea is to use `std::getline`, then truncate the string or validate that the string has only length 4.